# MySQLCommandBuilder and foreign key

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I have a pretty standard MySQL-query in my winform application like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTable WHERE tblTable.tableID = " & variable
```

One of the fields is a foreign key. And when I try to add a record to my datagridview I get the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Can't MySQLCommandBuilder make INSERT-commands with tables containing foreign keys?

Comment: That "standard" query leaves you open to sql injection attacks. Don't use string concatenation to put variables into sql commands.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint is there to prevent behavior like this (for the sake of the integrity of the database). You are probably trying to insert a value that reference another table by a primary key that doesn't exist.

Try changing your foreign key value to a *existing* primary key within the other table.

Comment: It might happen that I'm not sending a value to that field which has reference to the other table, as I have hidden it from the datagridview. Do you know if there is another way to, send that value with the MySQLBuilder, or should I just make the INSERT manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the insert the record with this, but is not recommended

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

your select statement;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Foreign key check is to avoid inconsistency between tables, the correct way to do this is: first insert the foreing key in the main table then add the record on the child table